# Facebook Object Debugger: Curl Error : SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE SSL: no alternative certificate subject name

Tags: facebook, curl, ssl-certificate, facebook-opengraph

I am unable to test the open graph tags on a site using the Facebook object debugger (lint tool) (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/). The errors returned are:

```
Object at URL 'https://www.musicharvest.org/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

Curl Error : SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.musicharvest.org'
```

and the result is that no open graph tags are interpreted.

The site exists and the SSL certificate contains both www.musicharvest.org and musicharvest.org.

Does anybody have an idea as to what the problem might be here?

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this? a hint maybe? I am currently facing the same problem.

Comment: Sorry Rob, I didn't.

Answer (score 5):

Searching for this problem I noticed my normal "http" URL I put in the debugger pointed to my registrar, instead of my website. So a DNS thing i thought, and i was right. 
When i changed the ipv6 AAAA record of my domain and pointed it to the ipv6 address of my server, the "SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE SSL" error went away for my "https" links.

Maybe this also fixes it for you.

Seems like Facebook does some things with ipv6

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The problem is that Facebook addressed to my website using IPv6 protocol. The solution was to delete AAAA records in DNS manager on my hosting. After when I deleted it all started working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an IPV6 problem. 
This is a HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) problem - just turn it off.
If your site is not a bank, it is a online store, there is no need to enable it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem for myself when I discovered a mistake in the content of the `og:url` Open Graph meta tag

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.domain_with_typo.com" />
```

Check the spelling of your domain name, confirm the subdomain and the protocol.