# Facebook scraper seeing page as blank

Tags: facebook, apache, joomla, facebook-sharer

I have installed Facebook like, share and comment buttons on my website and most of functionalities seem to be working ok, but after sharing a page on Facebook, thumbnail shows a blank page (clicking thumbnail takes user to the shared page, so there's no problem with that). Apparently this is how Facebook scraper sees my whole website.

I have determined that the probable cause is that the scraper (for some reason unknown to me) looks for website files in /var/www directory of my server, while website is located at /var/www/websitename/web. I have no idea what causes this, nor was I able to somehow direct Facebook scraper to correct path. What can I do to make everything work properly? I am using Debian+Apache+ISPConfig, website runs on Joomla!.

Comment: You can see what Facebook sees [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). That might help you figure out what's really going on.

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly how I determined for sure Facebook sees a blank page. The only errors debugger gives is that necessary og metatags are missing on that site, but it's blank, so no surprise. Pages on my actual website have them included.

Comment: What's the URL you're checking? Are you doing any sort of redirection, or attempting to customize the meta tags?

Comment: Here's an example page you can share on Facebook from my webiste: https://tls24.eu/index.php/aktualnosci-tls24/398-wiecej-bezplatnych-drog-ekspresowych

Only redirection I'm doing is 301 redirect from all HTTP traffic to HTTPS, but turning normal HTTP traffic back didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Maybe this is the cause: `Curl Error : SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE SSL: certificate subject name 'ks212275.kimsufi.com' does not match target host name 'tls24.eu'`

Comment: Though page was blank even as HTTP page, thanks, I will try investigating and fixing that error. Will update whether it helps anything or not.

Comment: Well, I have found similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713776/facebook-object-debugger-curl-error-ssl-peer-certificate-ssl-no-alternative
There are no answers and problem seems to be the same as mine. I'm pretty positive my SSL certificate has subject name tls24.eu included,but Facebook scraper continues to amuse me.

Comment: Hello and good day dear Dev Kosnik - many thanks for the question:  well i found out that we can scrape fb eg: see here: https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/
question: well can i scrape fb pages for a special key category - eg. 
female and  single  - is this possible!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the problem is solved. It was not SSL issue, nor any bug with code on my site. The problem was with Apache virtual host being configured for xx.xx.xx.xx:80 and xx.xx.xx.xx:443. Changing that to *:80 and *:443 automagically solved every problem Facebook scraper ever listed. Leaving this answer in case someone ever needs it.